# What is differences between glVertexAttribPointer and glVertexAttrib1f

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, opengl-4

In opengl es 2.0 when I wanted to change the attribute named "a_degree" in vertex shader at first I used glVertexAttribPointer and glEnableVertexAttribArray with true parameters but the behaviour is totally different when I used glVertexAttrib1f why?

here is my shaders code:

```
const char* CGraphic::VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE =
"attribute vec4 a_position;     \n"
"attribute vec2 a_texCoord;     \n"
"attribute vec4 a_color;        \n"
"attribute float a_degree;      \n"
"varying lowp vec4 v_color;     \n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;       \n"
"void main()                    \n"
"{                              \n"
"   float radianS = a_degree*   "
"   (3.14159265/180.0);         \n"
"   float s = sin(radianS);     \n"
"   float c = cos(radianS);     \n"
"   mat4 mvpMatrix=mat4(        \n"
"       c,-s,0,0,               "
"       s,c,0,0,                "
"       0,0,1,0,                "
"       0,0,0,1);             \n"
"   v_color = a_color;        \n"
"   gl_Position = a_position*mvpMatrix; \n"
"   v_texCoord = a_texCoord;  \n"
"}                            \n";

const char* CGraphic::FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE =
"precision mediump float;     \n"
"                             \n"
"varying vec4 vColor;         \n"
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;     \n"
"uniform sampler2D s_texture; \n"
"                             \n"
"void main()                  \n"
"{                            \n"
"  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );\n"
"}                            \n";
```

use with:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( m_shaderData.rotateLoc );
glVertexAttribPointer ( m_shaderData.rotateLoc, 1, GL_FLOAT,
                            GL_FALSE, 0, &degree );
```

vs

```
glVertexAttrib1f(m_shaderData.rotateLoc,degree);
```

In fact glVertexAttrib1f work fine in this situation and my texture rotate correctly but with glVertexAttribPointer just one point of the texture rotate that isn't my desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glVertexAttrib` allows you to specify a fixed value for the attribute.

In contrast, `glVertexAttribPointer` when enabled via `glEnableVertexAttribArray` allows you to specify a unique value for each vertex.

Read more here:
https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml
https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml

So, if you are drawing a triangle with multiple points, you would need to specify a separate degree for each point when using `glVertexAttribPointer`.  Thus, `degree` would need to be a `float[]`, while it looks like you're only specifying a single value right now as a `float`.

Most likely the values after `degree` in memory are zeros, which is why the other points are not rotating.

If you want the value to be the same, you CAN use `glVertexAttrib`.  If you're never going to specify it per vertex, using a uniform value is likely better.